# Cant access windows 10 after dual boot with debian 11

Tags: debian, windows

I have just installed a Debian 11 in dual boot with a pre installed windows 10 in a dell notebook. To make the dual boot and access Debian, i had to access the UEFI and:

1 - Alter the boot order so that it privileges the debian partition;

2 - Disable the secure boot option;

3 - Alter the SATA settings from SATA to AHCI;

So now the debian works just fine with the GRUB interface and all. However, if i try to access windows via GRUB interface, it just reinitializes the computer. So to actually access windows i need to enter the UEFI again and revert all changes. But then Debian will be unavailable, so if i want to access debian i need to access the UEFI again and revert changes again and so and so...

Also, sometimes when i access windows it states that it hasnt been initialized correcltly and needs to enter repair mode or try again.

Is there a way i can just have my old pal GRUB working normally and initializing both debian and windows again?

Comment: Did you run `update-grub`? What is the result of `efibootmgr`? Also: did you disable Win10's fast strartup?

Comment: Did you install the AHCI drivers into Windows first? Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems & 
But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works
 Is Debian installed in UEFI boot mode? Not CSM/Legacy/BIOS?

Comment: @FelixJN i didnt run update-grub and as i try to run it now it results in command not found. efibootmgr does recognize the windows boot manager and i disabled win10 fast startup.
oldfred answer did work however, so i believe the problem was trying to boot windows without using the correct AHCI configurations

Comment: @oldfred That solved it. Seems like the problem was trying to boot windows with the wrong SATA configuration. Can you post this as an answer please? And yes, Debian was installed in UEFI boot mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the AHCI drivers into Windows first?
And Windows & Linux need to be in same boot mode or both UEFI.

Windows AHCI instructions - some have found safeboot method better

https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-M-2-FAQ-regarding-AHCI-vs-RAID-ON-Storage-Drivers-M-2-Lanes/td-p/5072571

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems &

But if you do a safe boot first to update Windows, then boot to UEFI/BIOS and change to AHCI and finally boot normally, it works

Note that grub2's os-prober is currently being turned off by default for some secuity reason.

Grub 2.06 turns off os-prober

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-22.04-Multi-Boot-Changes

Os-prober now turned off by default Dec 2021

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2469993

Comment: I used the safe boot to change the SATA configurations from RAID to AHCI and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be relevant. It helped me in a similar situation.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems